# Good practice for a html button with image as background and uses href

Tags: html, css

I've been reading on how to implement a button. There are *a lot of answers*.

None go into *why* a specific version is preferred over the other. What is the *standard good practice* way of today?

The button I am specifically looking for is an `image` (no text), uses `href` and has to `submit`.

I've come up with the following but it is not working:

```
<button class="btn-googleplus" href="/auth/google" type="submit"></button>

<input type="submit" class="btn-googleplus" />

button .btn-googleplus {
    background-image: url("img/googleplus.png") no-repeat center center;
}
```

I've seen variants like this (I dislike as it seems complicated to have an `img` inside the button tag):

```
<button href="/auth/google" type="submit">
    <img id="img" src="img/googleplus.png" />
</button>
```

Comment: Button type submit will submit form data to called form action ! Then y do u need to give a href link ? That too inside a button ? Use anchor or button type submit ! Coz href inside is invalid markup. Or simply go for onclick(); and for styling, use background image and turn border :0

Comment: Remove the space between `button` and `.btn-googleplus`.

Comment: [**Links are not buttons. Neither are DIVs and SPANs**](http://www.karlgroves.com/2013/05/14/links-are-not-buttons-neither-are-divs-and-spans/)

Comment: `<input type="image">`?

Comment: @Paulie_D +1 *Finally* a good explanation. I can't believe I've missed *link* vs *button* all these years.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `href` to a `button` won't work. You need to put the button in a form wherein you specify your href value (the url) in the action attribute.

```
<form action="/auth/google">
    <button href="/auth/google" type="submit">
        <img id="img" src="img/googleplus.png" />
    </button>
</form>
```